# Defining non-standard accessor methods using 'attr_accessor'

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering if it is possible to use `attr_accessor` to reference an attribute with a different name than the methods it will define. For example, I have a class `GameWindow` with an attribute `bg_color`, and I want `attr_accessor` to define methods `background` and `background=`. Is there any way to do this, or do I have to define the methods myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr_accessor` in conjunction with `alias_method`. For example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  alias_method :baz, :bar
  alias_method :baz=, :bar=

  def initialize
  end
end
```

Then verify it works as expected:

```
foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x00007fabb12229a0>
foo.bar = 'foobar'
=> 'foobar'
foo.baz
=> 'foobar'
foo.baz = 'barfoo'
=> 'barfoo'
foo.bar
=> 'barfoo'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want an attr_accessor to define the methods background and background=. attr_accessor is used to define getter and setter for instance variable & method is something which return value but you cannot have setter like background= for method.

Please check with [alias_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods/alias_attribute) & [alias_method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method).

Comment: Note that `alias_attribute` is a Rails' method.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` [creates the instance variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) (here, `@bg_color`; or more precisely, makes it accessible to call on the object, though as Cary and Jörg point out below, the instance variable isn't strictly created until it is assigned) and reader and writer methods named after the symbol arguments you use. If you want it to be named `background`, why don't you just change the name?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I just don't understand why you would want to use two different names for the same variable. I can imagine cases, but if it's entirely up to you, I think the easiest way forward is just to rename `@bg_color` to `@background`. Why not?

Comment: `attr_accessor` only creates the two methods, not the instance variable: `class K; attr_accessor :cat; end; K.new.instance_variables #=>[]; class K; def initialize; @cat = 1; end; end; K.new.instance_variables #=> [:@cat]`. You could instead write `attr_accessor 'cat'`.

Comment: Well, it "defines a named attribute": https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor

This works: `class K; attr_accessor :cat; end; felix = K.new; felix.cat = 'felix';` All done without adding `@cat` anywhere.

Comment: That's curious that the doc for `attr_accessor` states that it creates the instance variable, yet , as I mentioned, `K.new.instance_variables #=>[]`.

Comment: Maybe the point is that `attr_accessor` makes the variable accessible (so I can add `felix.instance_variables` to my script and get `#=> [:@cat]`; it wasn't *declared* when I wrote `felix.cat = 'felix'`, it was *assigned* then), whether or not it is accessed. But if it isn't accessed, it isn't assigned and in that sense it isn't created, as you demonstrated. So it's a semantic issue.

Comment: Instances variables are created when they are first assigned. So, the first call to `#background=` will create the instance variable, unless of course it has been created earlier by a different assignment. `attr`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor` do *not* create instance variables. That would be a waste of space, since oftentimes, setters aren't actually called and dereferencing a non-existent instance variable is perfectly safe (it will just evaluate to `nil` but not raise an exception). So, there is no need to create an instance variable right away, you only need to create it when it …

Comment: … actually has a value.

Comment: Cary and Jorg are raising a point it's impossible to gainsay. I'm just trying to understand what the Ruby doc might mean. One way to think about what the Ruby doc is getting at is that, in my example, `felix.cat = 'felix'` would raise an error without `attr_accessor :cat` in the class definition. Ruby requires the accessor in order to make the attribute value available to set; it isn't like JavaScript, where `felix.cat = 'felix'` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: I.e., it would be perfectly fine without any mention of `cat` in the original object or prototype definition.

Comment: @globewalldesk This is not an answer to the question. You are asking "Why don't you just change the name?" without providing an answer to the original question. Requests for clarification on questions should be added as comments to the original question, not posted as answers. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): "You should submit a comment if you want to request clarification from the author."

Comment: Sorry, @anothermh I thought I was just imitating all the programmers I’ve asked “how do I?” questions of, when they answered, “well, you shouldn’t be doing that.” Clearly I haven’t learned all of the many rules of this website!

Comment: Should I try to delete my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
attr_accessor :background
```

is a just a simple macro that generates these two methods for you:

```
def background
  @background
end

def background=(value)
  @background = value
end
```

When you want to have a getter and a setter method with a specific name but assign the value to a variable with a different name then just write the methods yourself - for example like this:

```
def background
  @bg_color
end

def background=(value)
  @bg_color = value
end
```